# Dismissing Storyboards Without Navigation Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, view, segue, viewcontroller

I am currently running an application with a MenuVC allowing users to pick their choice of four segues to present other VC's. When these four buttons/segues are triggered, a new VC is presented **by method of showing**. To deal with the problem of constantly increasing the memory usage because the VC's are being placed on top of each other, I have attempted to **dismiss VC's in the segues as new VC's are being presented**. The problem is, this logic does not work with my application, because the non Menu VC's can trigger segues to each other, thus c**reating problems with which VC is exactly shown after dismissal** (Menu can show Records, and Records can show Options, causing issues with what VC is supposed to be on top).

*I was wondering if there is a way to solve the issue of dismissing    the VC's to free up memory without the implementation of a    NavigationControllers as I have already progressed this far not using them.*

For reference here is how I am presenting/dismissing each VC.

```
  @IBAction func moveToOptions(_ sender: Any) {
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toOptionsSegue", sender: nil)
       AVAudioPlayer.playSpecAudio(audioPiece: "Click", volume: 0.7)
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that this code dismisses then segues ?

Comment: One way out is you can put these 4 view controllers in a tab bar, and button actions can display the appropriate tab.

Comment: @ – Sh_Khan Yes. If I look at memory usage, the movement from one VC to another does not utilize any memory. Though, even though I have this code in both directions, it is still using 1/2 of the memory that would have been used without the dismissals, every cycle. The logic is flawed in how it moves between VC's. That's where I am confused. Any idea why this could be?